# Getting contents of dropdown from table and storing it in an array

Tags: php, html, mysql

I just want to get the contents of the dropdown and store it in array.

I am able to display the dropdown but it doesn't get the contents of what I selected.

```
echo '<br><br><br><br><br>
    <div class="Table">
        <table border="2pt solid black" align="left" cellpadding="2px" bordercolor=black>
            <tr>
                <td width = "7%">
                    <div align = "left"><b>BRAND NAME</div></b>
                </td>
                <td width = "7%">
                    <div align = "left"><b>INGREDIENT</div></b>
                </td>
                <td width = "3%">
                    <div align = "left"><b>QUANTITY</div></b>
                </td>
                <td width = "7%">
                    <div align = "left"><b>MEASUREMENT</div></b>
                </td>
            </tr>';

for ($x = 0; $x < sizeof($rowarray); $x++) {
    $query = "select R.name AS RAWNAME, I.name AS INGREDIENTNAME, R.quantity AS RAWQUANTITY from rawmaterial R JOIN ingredient I ON R.ingredient_id = I.ingredient_id where R.rawmaterial_id='{$rowarray[$x]}'";
    $res = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
    while ($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<tr>
            <td width=\"7%\">
                <div align=\"left\">{$fetch['RAWNAME']}</div>
            </td>
            <td width=\"3%\">
                <div align=\"left\">{$fetch['INGREDIENTNAME']}</div>
            </td>
            <td width=\"3%\">
                <div align=\"left\"><input type='name' name='quantity[]' placeholder={$fetch['RAWQUANTITY']}></input></div>
            </td>
            <td width=\"7%\">
                <div align=\"left\">";
        echo "<select name = 'measure'>";
        $mesr = mysqli_query($dbc, 'select measure from measure_ref');
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($mesr, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $mes = $row['measure'];
            echo '<option value ='.$mes.'>'.$mes.'</option>';
        }
        echo "</select>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";   
    }       
}     

echo '</table></div>';
$messarray = array();
$mes = $_POST['measure'];
$row = array();
foreach ($mes as $row) {
    array_push($messarray, $row);
}
```

Comment: In case you guys are wondering there is also a submit button, I am able to get all the other contents but I cant get the drop down contents

Comment: So, what does your http servers error log file say and what is the final html markup your http server sends out?

Comment: this is the error
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Ok, so you have the location of the specific issue. That is something you can work from, right? Obviously that means that `$_POST['measure']` is not an array as you expect. Since you implemented no error detection or handling at all you stumble into that error. I cannot say if that is when you create the form or when the form is submitted, your code is pretty unclear. You should separate the code preparing and sending the form from the code processing the submitted form. Next you should separate code that fetches data from the database and the code creating the html markup using that code.

Comment: i fixed it already, all i needed to do was add a class

Answer (score 0):

Check below points.

1. Make sure your dropdown is within form
2. As you are creating multiple dropdown you should give name with '[]'(measure[]),like you have given to 'quantity[]'.

Comment: i have tried changing it to this "<select name = 'measure[]'> it still does not work